# Pegar texto do scene builder para tela de criar conta

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Como faço pra pegar texto do arquivo FXML?

campo do arquivo FXML:

```
<TextField fx:id="usernameSU" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
```

arquivo Controller:

```
public class signUpController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TextField usernameSU;

    @FXML
    private void signUp(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(""); //Imprimir TextField para teste
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        usernameSU = new TextField();
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não entende a sua pergunta, mas para obter o valor de um `TextField`, só tem que usar o método `.getText()`.
Na contoladora, no método `initialize`, não precisa de inicializar novamente o `TextField`.

```
 usernameSU.getText();
```

No SceneBuilder, precisa definir a Controladora do arquivo FXML.